# How do I make my discord bot react with a random emoji?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I'm working with discord.js and with my bot, I've been trying to make it react with random emojis whenever someone sends a message. This is what I have so far with some lines commented because I don't know what to do with them. (I'm using custom emojis)

top:

```
var emojisnop = [":vibing:698328721383227392",":snoopy5:724412122703855747",":snoopy4:724411949281968131",":snoopy3:724411826430804018",":snoopy2:724411667106103437"];
```

bottom:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message) {
    return emojisnop = emojisnop[Math.floor(Math.random() * emojisnop.length)]
        message.react(':vibing:698328721383227392')
    }
});
```

Any help would be wonderful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top:

```
var emojisnop = [":vibing:698328721383227392",":snoopy5:724412122703855747",":snoopy4:724411949281968131",":snoopy3:724411826430804018",":snoopy2:724411667106103437"];
var emojirandom
```

bottom:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message) {
      emojirandom = emojisnop[Math.floor(Math.random() * emojisnop.length)]
        message.react(emojirandom)
    }
});
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var emojisnop = ["698328721383227392","724412122703855747","724411949281968131","724411826430804018","724411667106103437"];

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message) {
    return emojisnop = emojisnop[Math.floor(Math.random() * emojisnop.length)]
        message.react(emojisnop)
    }
});
```

For `custom emojis` use emoji ID